# Site crashing in iPhone 4S and 5

Tags: iphone, mobile, safari

My website is http://www.delizie.eu/ and it is crashing in iPhone 4S and 5 in Safari and Chrome Browser at the very load of the first slide. I have been unsuccessful in finding the solution. Please help me to find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: may be cause of low internet speed

Comment: Did you tested in your iPhone?

Comment: i tested. it also working fine in Pc

Comment: @Bhanu: Can you do one more test for me that if the "Assortimento" section is loading 7 items in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website loads correctly on my iPhone 5 device and on a iPhone simulator. If you like to to see a console of the logs, HTTP request and errors i would suggest you use Safari developer mode. Go to [Apple site here](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) for a guide.

Some suggestion i have is to optimize your site as to load the complete site with all the rich media content its takes about 30 - 45 seconds as there 4mb of content to be downloaded. Use [Google PageSpeed insight](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http://www.delizie.eu/) to get a breakdown of improvements such as minifying JS, CSS and reducing images etc...

You should also think about reducing the amount of request that been site to the server, in total there 98 request which about 50 of them are images. Using a well known CSS technique like [image sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) allows you to reduce the number of server requests and save bandwidth by combining collection of images into a single image. Other technique you could use is [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP)

Take a look at Wordpress plugins that can help with speed [w3-total-cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) which adds better caching compared to the default option and also [Smuch.it by Yahoo](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/) which reduces image size. Here a [guide](http://upcity.com/blog/2014/01/top-20-tips-to-increase-your-wordpress-site-page-load-speed/) on other things you can do to improve your site

Comment: I have reduced the page size by 1MB but still the site crashes. Attached a video: http://youtu.be/UUpvOxM5GnY

Comment: I've checked on iOS6 everything seems to be working fine, have you tried on another device and different iOS version such as iOS7